# execute preparedStatement in getSqlMapClientTemplate

Tags: spring, jdbc, ibatis

I want to execute prepardStatement in getsqlMapClientTemplate() method.One of preparedStatement parameter value is received by another query result.Is it possible to execute like this?

like

```
String query="select Id_no from employee";
String resultQuery="select empSalary from employeePay where Id=?";
prepareStatement ps=con.preprepareStatement(query); // Instead of connection reference i want to use getSqlMapClientTemplate
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()){
//pst.setInt(1,rs.getInt(1)); // here if i want to pass dynamic value to execute resultQuery
  pst.setInt(1,userGivenValue);
PrepareStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(resultQuery); //
pst.executeQuery();
```

forpreparedStatement instead of connection object i want to use getSqlMapClientTemplate() method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a `SqlMapClientTemplate` you want a `JdbcTemplate` instead.

Next your solution is flawed as it falls into the 1+N select problem, ie. you execute a single query to get a list of ids then for each id issue another query. Creating a single query which does everything in one shot is more effecient.

```
final String query = "select empSalary from employeePay where Id in (select Id_no from employee)" 
JdbcTemplate template = getJdbcTemplate();
List<Long> salaries = template.queryForList(query, Long.class);
```

Something like that.

Or if you want to use the `SqlMapClientTemplate` simply add the query to the ibatis configuration and let iBatis (instead of the `JdbcTemplate`) handle the hard lifting for you.

Comment: if i want to add dynamic values for query means, like we are setting parameters in prepareStatement, is there any way to do like that in sqlmapclientTemplate?

Comment: Define dynamic here? Please modify your question to express this (as currently you don't mention anything about that).

Comment: Added line from your comments

Comment: You still haven't explained what is dynamic about your query.

Comment: more clearly i want getSqlMapClientTemplate("select empSalary from employeePay where Id=empId",empId);                                                    is this possible?

Comment: As stated that isn't efficient. But if you must why wouldn't you be able to do that, simply use the normal iBatis support for that. At least I suspect that that is what you are using as you are using the `SqlMapClientTemplate`.